# What is the structure of a simple threaded gui application using Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to wrap my head around threading and gui applications so I can start to build them.  I downloaded the Qt SDK but am a bit lost.

Just so I can understand how this works, I want to create a gui application that consists of a text box and two buttons.  Each button would start a new thread (so 3 could be running at the same time: the main gui thread, and the 2 initiated from the buttons), and each would have access to the information in the text box.  How would I set this application up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at SIGNAL and SLOTS it's the base of Qt .

After you done that take a look at QThread and QThreadPool.

Also i recommend these awsome tutorials : http://www.voidrealms.com/tutorials.aspx?filter=qt

Comment: Thank you, I'm checking out the videos now

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect a slot to the QPushButton clicked signal and kickstart a new thread from that slot as shown below.

`QPushButton *button=new QPushButton();`

```
connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(startthread()));
```

And the slot startthread will kickstart the the new thread with a worker class

```
void MyClass::startthread()
  {
       QThread *thread=new QThread();
       WorkerClass * worker=new WorkerClass();
       worker->moveToThread(thread);
       thread->start()
  }
```

Where WorkerClass will be executed in a separate thread.

Comment: I tried doing just that and I also tried another threading example.  I can't get my threads to start it seems.  I have a click event set up for a push button, and then when that event fires I use the code you have there.  Then in my worker class overridden "run" function I make another dialog.  But that dialog never fires.  Do you have any idea why my threads don't start?   Could it have anything to do with  me using Windows on a Mac messing up the threading library?

Comment: Qt widgets are always created in the main thread(GUI thread)...so you should not create Widgets(QDialog) in separate thread....instead you should only access data from another thread and update the gui on the main thread

Comment: Here a link that explains this:http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/thread-basics.html